# Pilea Dark Mystery Drooping

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants

My pilea dark mystery is really drooping. I haven’t a clue why because I’ve watered when the soil is dry- ie: about once a week. I haven’t had it for long. Only thing I can think of is I re-potted it twice in a short time because it was in the plastic nursery pot and then I put it in a pot that was too small so I decided to put it in the one it’s in now.

I’m so confused because the leaves aren’t dry and crispy so I don’t think it’s a humidity issue. But I really don’t know. I love love this plant so I’d really like to salvage it.

[image]

Comment: Is there a drainage hole in the pot (assuming its in a pot inside the hanging pot)? Or no drainage at all? How long have you had the plant?

Comment: The best place for a plant such as this is the high humidity of a terrarium. You have suggested that this is not the problem, but I am not convinced. As a test, put the whole thing in a closed cardboard box or a large plastic bag overnight and see if the leaves perk up a bit.